# When a Post comment is made, no more can be created, only shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, comments, posts

I am trying to get a post and comment system working, for this however i want only one comment to be made per post. Only as i am trying to create a system as where content will be displayed followed by a comment 7 times in one post... Example...

**program model 1 body content 1**

Commentmodel1

**program model 1 body content 2**

Commentmodel2

**program model 1 body content 3**

Commentmodel3

.etc.etc.

For Me this is the simplest way of being able todo this by creating 7 different comment models, i know there is probably an easier way but as im new this seems the simplest. However i am struggling getting the one comment model to only allow just one comment to be made.

In this application coach is the user.

Here are the files involved, For the Models, program is the basic Post model, and comments is comments.

programs/Show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b><br />
  <%= @program.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Body:</b><br />
  <%= @program.cweekcomments %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_program_path(@program) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', programs_path %>

<br /><br /><br />
<i>Comments</i>
<% @program.comments.each do |comment| %> 
  <p>
    <b>Comment:</b>

    <% if comment %>
        <%= comment.body %>
        <br />
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_program_comment_path(@program, comment) %> | <%= link_to 'Destroy', [@program, comment] , method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <% else %>
        <%= form_for([@program, @program.comments.build]) do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :body %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </p>  
<% end %>
```

Programs_controller.rb

```
class ProgramsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_coach!, :except => [:show]


  # GET /programs
  # GET /programs.json

  def index
    @programs = Program.find_all_by_coach_id(current_coach[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @programs }
    end
  end

  # GET /programs/1
  # GET /programs/1.json
  def show
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @program }
    end
  end

  # GET /programs/new
  # GET /programs/new.json
  def new
    @program = Program.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @program }
    end
  end

  # GET /programs/1/edit
  def edit
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /programs
  # POST /programs.json
  def create
    @program = Program.new(params[:program])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @program.save
        format.html { redirect_to @program, notice: 'Program was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @program, status: :created, location: @program }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @program.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /programs/1
  # PUT /programs/1.json
  def update
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @program.update_attributes(params[:program])
        format.html { redirect_to @program, notice: 'Program was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @program.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /programs/1
  # DELETE /programs/1.json
  def destroy
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])
    @program.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to programs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @comment = @program.comments.build
  end 

  def create
    @program = Program.find(params[:program_id])
    @comment = @program.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to program_path(@program)
  end

  def destroy
    @program = Program.find(params[:program_id])
    @comment = @program.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to program_path(@program)
  end

  def edit
    @program = Program.find(params[:program_id])
    @comment = @program.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

   def update
    @program = Program.find(params[:program_id])
    @comment = @program.comments.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      #if @program.comments.update_attributes(params[:comment])
      if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
        format.html { redirect_to program_path(@program), notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
      end
    end

end
```

In advance, thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: If you want only one comment to be added for a post, just do the check in `CommentsController#create`. If `@program` already has a comment, do not create a new one.

Comment: how would i go about doing that? sorry new to RoR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your program comment relation to has_one.(has_one :comment in your program.rb)

```
def create
   @program = Program.find(params[:program_id])
   if @program.comment
     flash[:error] = "Cannot comment more than once"
   else
     @comment = @program.comments.create(params[:comment])
     flash[:notice] = "Comment created"
   end
   redirect_to program_path(@program)
end
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, when i change to has_one, i get an erorr coming back saying undefined method 'each' at <% @program.comment.each do |comment| %> what should i change this to?

Comment: @program.comment doesn't return an array now. You don't have to iterate through it.

Comment: ok thats cool, so ive now changed <%= comment.body %> to <%= @program.comment.body %> which now isnt returning an error, however how do i now build the form to create a comment? at the moment i have <%= form_for([@program, @program.comment.build]) do |f| %> but it dosnt like it :(!

Comment: `build` can only be used on collection. Replace it with `@program.build_comment`